# decltype with two parameters, = decltype(a,b), for function return type

Tags: c++, sfinae

I met a `decltype()` with two parameters as return value type of template function:

```
template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((void)(c.*f)(), void()) { }
```

Does someone knows what is the second parameter, `void()`?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the expression `(void)(c.*f)(), void()`:

- `(void)(c.*f)()` serves to check that `f` is a member function in `c` that can be called with no arguments; it doesn't matter what the member-function return type is anyway, but it's nominally cast to `void`
- if the above is valid, the comma operator discards it and considers the second part, such that the overall effect is per `decltype(void())`, which yields a `void` type

Praetorian comments below that the trailing `, void()` is redundant, as the leading part is cast to `void` (the C-style cast `(void)`) anyway... I suspect the `, void()` is intended as documentation, highlighting the `enable_if`-like conditional selection of a return type, it's a style choice whether to shorten that further to `decltype((c.*f)(), void())`.

## Further details / example

This can be used for [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), though [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is more self-documenting.  Consider this code, and the comments in `main()` (CT stands for Compile Time):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((void)(c.*f)(), void())
    { std::cout << "member function\n"; }

template<class C>
void test(C c, int)
    { std::cout << "int\n"; }

struct X {
    int f() { return 42; }
    double g(int) { return 3.14; }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    test(x, &X::f);  // ok - outputs "member function\n"
    // test(x, &X::g);  // CT error - g needs an argument
    test(x, 99);   // ok - outputs "int\n"
}
```

Output:

```
member function
int
```

You can see and run the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0578b0aa65556a4f).

Comment: Thank you for answering it, Tony D. It seems decltype checks  c has a member function void f(). Please let me confirm the part of "if the above is valid". Is it "if the above is invalid"? I am confused because both parameter returns void. If I misunderstand anything. I apologize for confirming above.Thank you very much.

Comment: _"both parameter returns void"_ Eh?

Comment: The `, void()` part is redundant since the return type of the function is being cast to `void` anyway

Comment: return type of (void)(c.*f)()  and void() are void. If (void)(c.*f)() is valid, why it does not apply decltype( (void)(c.*f)() ) ? That confuses me. I am beginner of c++. So I am afraid I am asking something strange. If so, please forgive me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, Praetorian. I understand the second parameter void() is redundant. I don't know why but the original code I found might have some reasons to do so. Thank you again.

Comment: I learned that the first augment is a valid checker for SFINAE. Now I understand why decltype() needs to have two parameters, valid checker (=the first augment) and return type(=the second augment). Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: @mora: that's right... if there's another version of `test` that unambiguously supports some other argument types, it can still match and satisfy the caller.

Comment: Thank you Tony D. You and other people led me to deeper understanding of c++. It is fun.

Comment: @mora: you're welcome - and you were first to explicitly mention SFINAE... well done!  Cheers.